# Adding library to Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, log4j

I have created simple Maven Java project in Eclipse.

[image]

In package `src/main/java` I have create simple `tst` class and planing to use `log4j` there:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class tst {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hello");
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

I have added log4j in dependencies:

[image]

I expect Maven will download log4j jar for my project. Instead of that I have error `Missing artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2`.

How to fix this problem?
Is it possible to know what versions are available in log4j project?

Comment: Can you share pour pom.xml file content?

Comment: What options have you checked in Window->Preferences->Maven? You image shows disable index downloads, try activating them as well as artifact downloads.

Comment: Are you sure the version is 1.2? Maven central shows versions from 1.2.4 to 1.2.17...

Comment: @Raedwald According to the image, OP is using eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

[mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com) says that the project `Apache Log4j` was move to `Log4j Core`.
So try to update the artifact with this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When you add a library with Maven, always check the correct version in *mvnrepository.com*

And if you still have the error, try to update maven dependencies. 
Right click on the project and select

```
Maven -> Update Project
```

Sometimes when you update project libraries with Maven, Eclipse isn't able to download it directly and you have to force the refresh of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that there is no log4j in version 1.2.

Try version 1.2.17.

Just follow the path you chose, but use 1.2.17 instead of 1.2.